# jQuery counter insert commas to break up string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, counter

I have a counter that increments every x seconds, here's my code:

```
var counter=22000000000;
if(typeof(localStorage.getItem('counts'))!='object') {
   counter=parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counts'));
}
$(".count").html(counter);
setInterval(function () {
    $(".count").html(counter);
    ++counter;
    localStorage.setItem('counts',counter);
}, 18000);
```

Because the starting number is so high it doesn't read well, see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vpju4cpr/1/

Ideally instead of outputting `22000000000` I'd like it to read `22,000,000,000`

How can I do this?

Comment: Try searching first:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript).

I googled "javascript insert commas into number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .html() function, change  `counter` to `counter.toLocaleString()`
like this:

```js
var counter=22000000000;
 if(typeof(localStorage.getItem('counts'))!='object') {
    counter=parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counts'));
 }
 $(".count").html(counter.toLocaleString());
 setInterval(function () {
     $(".count").html(counter.toLocaleString());
     ++counter;
     localStorage.setItem('counts',counter);
 }, 18000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To format a number with comma, you can use this regex:

```
var counterString = counter.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
$(".count").html(counterString );
```

> **input**: 199999999
>
> **output**: "199,999,999"